# Flask - Handling Form File & Upload to AWS S3 without Saving to File

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, buffer, protocol-buffers

I am using a Flask app to receive a mutipart/form-data request with an uploaded file (a video, in this example).

I don't want to save the file in the local directory because this app will be running on a server, and saving it will slow things down.

I am trying to use the file object created by the Flask request.files[''] method, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is that portion of the code:

```
@bp.route('/video_upload', methods=['POST'])
def VideoUploadHandler():
    form = request.form
    video_file = request.files['video_data']
    if video_file:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.upload_file(video_file.read(), S3_BUCKET, 'video.mp4')
        return json.dumps('DynamoDB failure')
```

This returns an error:

```
TypeError: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

on the line:

```
s3.upload_file(video_file.read(), S3_BUCKET, 'video.mp4')
```

I did get this to work by first saving the file and then accessing that saved file, so it's not an issue with catching the request file.  This works:

```
video_file.save(form['video_id']+".mp4")
s3.upload_file(form['video_id']+".mp4", S3_BUCKET, form['video_id']+".mp4")
```

What would be the best method to handle this file data in memory and pass it to the `s3.upload_file()` method?  I am using the boto3 methods [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/s3.html#using-the-transfer-manager), and I am only finding examples with the filename used in the first parameter, so I'm not sure how to process this correctly using the file in memory.  Thanks!

Comment: have you managed this issue?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to be able to access the raw data sent to Flask. This is not as easy as it seems, since you're reading a form. To be able to read the raw stream you can use `flask.request.stream`, which behaves similarly to `StringIO`. The trick here is, you *cannot* call `request.form` or `request.file` because accessing those attributes will load the whole stream into memory or into a file.

You'll need some extra work to extract the right part of the stream (which unfortunately I cannot help you with because it depends on how your form is made, but I'll let you experiment with this).

Finally you can use the `set_contents_from_file` function from boto, since `upload_file` does not seem to deal with file-like objects (`StringIO` and such).

Example code:

```
from boto.s3.key import Key

@bp.route('/video_upload', methods=['POST'])
def VideoUploadHandler():
    # form = request.form <- Don't do that
    # video_file = request.files['video_data'] <- Don't do that either
    video_file_and_metadata = request.stream  # This is a file-like object which does not only contain your video file
    # This is what you need to implement
    video_title, video_stream = extract_title_stream(video_file_and_metadata)
    # Then, upload to the bucket
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = s3.create_bucket(bucket_name, location=boto.s3.connection.Location.DEFAULT)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = video_title
    k.set_contents_from_filename(video_stream)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Can you elaborate on `extract_title_stream(video_file_and_metadata)`?  I'm new to this, so I'm not sure where to start on extracting that stream that is different from what I was already doing.

Comment: Well as I said, that's specific to your forms, so you should have a look at it yourself... Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html. There may be a `get_value` method for `request.stream` but I'm not sure. IMO your best bet is to handle your files the way you used to handle them: it's safer and I'm not sure you need the extra performance.

Comment: It's probably because I'm new to the stringIO library and streaming, but I'm not sure how to convert a LimitedStream (`request.stream`) to stringIO.  I'm not finding much information on that online either.

Comment: BTW, I'm using a standard mutipart/form-data POST request, so the setup on that should be able to be anticipated since it has no abnormal features.  I just have two text fields and one file field.

Comment: You shouldn't convert it per say, but you should read it. IMO this might be too complex if you cannot do this part, and if you want extra performance out of this you may have to do some more complicated stuff, such as controlling the buffer sizes. Plus, it's a bit rude not to upvote or accept.

Comment: I apologize if I came off as rude.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to gather any usable information from your answer.  I think I gave all the information about my situation that I am able to give, so I was hoping for a bit more detail in how to implement this solution.  Please let me know if you can add some more detail.  I have not been able to be any more successful with `request.stream` than I was with `request.form` or `request.files`.

Comment: In that case I fear this particular problem is too advanced for you right now... Try using pdb and have a look at what request.stream looks like, but I can't help your more than I did